# How can I update an attribute in a through table?

Tags: sequelize.js

In Sequelize.js, how can I update an attribute in a `through` table for 1-N or N-M relationships? I tried to find documentation but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If user belongs to many projects, and the project has an enrolled column you can do

```
project.addUser(user, { enrolled: new Date() });
```

This should also work if the relation betwene user and project is already set, in that case the join table will be updated.

The docs are at the end of [this section](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations).

Comment: Is there a way to do it in a model instance's methods like `Project.update(...)` or `User.upsert(...)`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Can you perhaps create a full example and edit your post?

Comment: Is `project.addUser` the only way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, with the information you've given so far I believe so. But if you post a more complete example, I might be able to give you some more pointers

Comment: Is there a way to query the attributes of this join table and return them with your projects?