# How can I update a through-NM-attribute in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, mariadb

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689275/how-can-i-update-an-attribute-in-a-through-table) question and it didnt' help me, so I'm asking my own:

Let's suppose I have 2 tables joined by a NM through table using Sequelize and MariaDB:

```
User <-- UserItem --> Item
```

A single User can have many Items, and a single Item can belong to many Users. But I need a custom through attribute to store the quantity of the Item, let's call it Apples. So, according to the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations), this will be the definition:

```
var UserItem = Sequelize.define('UserItem', {
  quantity: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, 
  timestamps: false
});
models.Item.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'UserItem'});
models.User.belongsToMany(models.Item, {through: 'UserItem'});
```

And then I add a new relationship with the through attribute like this:

```
User.addItem(item, { quantity: 0 });
```

This works as expected. But, what if I need to update the quantity of an Item? I could do the following:

```
User.addItem(item, { quantity: 20 });
```

And the quantity of my Item will be updated to 20 in case of existing, and inserted otherwise. I don't want this. I want something like that:

```
User.addItem(item, { quantity: quantity + 1 });
```

But due to the impossibility to make queries to the join tables, I am unable to get the particular NM row for updating using the previous value.

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have the join table DAO as specified in the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#associating-objects).

In this case though you need to know if the `item` is new association or not.

So it will look something like.

```
User.hasItem( item )
    .then( exists => {

       if ( !exists ) { 
            return User.addItem( item, { quantity : 20 } ) 
       } else {
            item.UserItem.quantity += 1;
            return item.UserItem.save();
       }

    } )
```

You can read more about [hasAssociation in the docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#check-associations) as well.